# How to include an XSL file into another XSL file

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I need that `2.xsl` file use function for changing date format (tag `<Date>`) from file `1.xsl`. I use instruction `<xsl:include>` but I don't know what I should to change.

Here is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ClientList>
    <Client>
        <Name>Jan</Name>
        <Surname>Kowalski</Surname>
        <Date>2018-03-23</Date>
    </Client>
    <Client>
        <Name>Piotr</Name>
        <Surname>Nowak</Surname>
        <Date>2018-04-25</Date>
    </Client>
</ClientList>
```

My `1.xsl` file with function that changes date format:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <Date>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(Date, 9, 2), '-', substring(Date, 6, 2), '-', substring(Date, 1, 4))"/>
    </Date>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is my `2.xsl` file (I need that this file use function from `1.xsl`):

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:include href="1.xsl"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <ClientList>
            <xsl:for-each select="ClientList/Client">
                <Client>
                    <NameSurname>
                        <xsl:value-of select="concat(Name, ' ' , Surname)"/>
                    </NameSurname>
                </Client>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </ClientList>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I don't see any usable code in that first XSLT snippet, if you want to define a function then use `xsl:function`, if you want to define a template use `xsl:template`. But having a top level `Date` element is not even allowed so before you think about including a stylesheet you first need to write one that adheres to the rules of XSLT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are couple of issues with the XSLs created and rightly pointed out by @Martin Honnen in his comment related to `1.xsl`.

The `<Date>` format conversion logic needs to be wrapped inside an `<xsl:template>` or `<xsl:function>`. Below is the updated `1.xsl` that uses `<xsl:template>`.

```
<xsl:template name="DateConvertor">
    <Date>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(Date, 9, 2), '-', substring(Date, 6, 2), '-', substring(Date, 1, 4))"/>
    </Date>
</xsl:template>
```

In `2.xsl`, you are including `utils.xsl` which I believe corresponds to `1.xsl`. In this XSL, you need to invoke the template or function that you have created in the included XSL.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <ClientList>
        <xsl:for-each select="ClientList/Client">
            <Client>
                <NameSurname>
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat(Name, ' ', Surname)" />
                </NameSurname>
                <xsl:call-template name="DateConvertor" /> <!-- call the template here -->
            </Client>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </ClientList>
</xsl:template>
```

**EDIT** - Changes for using `<xsl:function>`

XSLT 2.0 allows writing of own functions using `<xsl:function>`. Functions can be used for performing any computational logic and they return values based on the computations. Parameters can be passed to the function using `<xsl:param>`. Functions have to be associated to a namespace which is different than the XSLT namespace.

The `1.xsl` will need to be modified to include a function which accepts a single parameter of type `string` and returns a value which is of type `string`.

```
<xsl:function name="ex:DateConvertor" as="xs:string">
    <xsl:param name="InputDate" as="xs:string" />
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring($InputDate, 9, 2), '-', substring($InputDate, 6, 2), '-', substring($InputDate, 1, 4))"/>
</xsl:function>
```

This function is associated with namespace `xmlns:ex="http://canbeanything"`. Additionally since the datatypes are being used for the parameter and return value, you need to define namespace `xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"` also.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:ex="http://canbeanything">
```

Changes in `2.xsl` to invoke the function `ex:DateConvertor`.

Map the namespace necessary for the function.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:ex="http://canbeanything">
```

Call Function and pass `Date` value as a parameter

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <ClientList>
        <xsl:for-each select="ClientList/Client">
            <Client>
                <NameSurname>
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat(Name, ' ', Surname)" />
                </NameSurname>
                <!-- Function Call -->
                <!-- passing value of 'Date' as parameter -->
                <Date>
                    <xsl:value-of select="ex:DateConvertor(Date)" /> 
                </Date>
            </Client>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </ClientList>
</xsl:template>
```

The required output can be achieved in a single XSL, but I am assuming that this is a learning phase and the above is probably an example of `<xsl:include>`.

Comment: can you show me please how to do this using function?

Comment: Updated the answer to include use of `<xsl:function>`. More details on user defined `<xsl:function>` can be found [here](https://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/09/03/trxml.html)